# Android: How to create a navigation bar

Tags: android

I  have seen some apps with a slightly translucent, black bar at the bottom of the screen with buttons on it and a menu bar in the middle. I was wondering how to create something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#AAFFFFFF">

    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/left_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView android:text="@string/your_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentCenter="true"/>

    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Pay attention to the `android:background` color I picked. It might be wrong.